# C++ should I use pointer or reference?

Tags: c++, pointers, reference, initializer-list

I would like to have an insight about whenever I should be using references or pointers.

Let's take the example of a Polygon class using a Rectangle class for its internal bounding box.

Polygon.h

```
class Polygon {

private:
    std::list<Point> _points;
    Rectangle _boundingBox;

public:
    Polygon(const std::list<Point> &);

public:
    const std::list<Point> &getPoints() const;
    const Rectangle &getBoundingBox() const;

private:
    void setBoundingBox();

};
```

Polygon.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include "Polygon.h"

Polygon::Polygon(const std::list<Point> &points)
{
    if (points.size() < polygon::MIN_SIDE + 1) {
        throw std::invalid_argument("A polygon is composed of at least 3 sides.");
    }

    if (points.front() != points.back()) {
        throw std::invalid_argument("A polygon must be closed therefore the first point must be equal to the last one.");
    }

    std::list<Point>::const_iterator it;
    for (it = ++points.begin(); it != points.end(); ++it) {
        this->_points.push_back(*it);
    }
    this->setBoundingBox();
}

void Polygon::translate(const std::array<float, 2> &vector)
{
    std::list<Point>::iterator it;
    for (it = this->_points.begin(); it != this->_points.end(); ++it) {
        (*it).setX((*it).getX() + vector[0]);
        (*it).setY((*it).getY() + vector[1]);
    }
    Point topLeft = this->_boundingBox->getTopLeft();
    Point bottomRight = this->_boundingBox->getBottomRight();

    topLeft.setX(topLeft.getX() + vector[0]);
    topLeft.setY(topLeft.getY() + vector[1]);
    bottomRight.setX(bottomRight.getX() + vector[0]);
    bottomRight.setY(bottomRight.getY() + vector[1]);
}

const std::list<Point> &Polygon::getPoints() const
{
    return this->_points;
}

const Rectangle &Polygon::getBoundingBox() const
{
    return this->_boundingBox;
}

void Polygon::setBoundingBox()
{
    float xMin = this->_points.front().getX();
    float xMax = this->_points.front().getX();
    float yMin = this->_points.front().getY();
    float yMax = this->_points.front().getY();

    std::list<Point>::const_iterator it;
    for (it = this->_points.begin(); it != this->_points.end(); ++it)
    {
        Point point = *it;
        if (point.getX() < xMin) {
            xMin = point.getX();
        }
        if (point.getX() > xMax) {
            xMax = point.getX();
        }
        if (point.getY() < yMin) {
            yMin = point.getY();
        }
        if (point.getY() > yMax) {
            yMax = point.getY();
        }
    }
    this->_boundingBox = new Rectangle(Point(xMin, yMin), Point(xMax, yMax));
}

std::ostream &operator<<(std::ostream &out, const Polygon &polygon)
{
    std::list<Point>::const_iterator it;

    for (it = polygon.getPoints().begin(); it != polygon.getPoints().end(); ++it) {
        out << (*it);
        if (it != polygon.getPoints().end()) {
            out << " ";
        }
    }
    return out;
}
```

Rectangle.h

```
#pragma once

#include <stdexcept>

#include "Point.h"

class Rectangle {

private:
    Point _topLeft;
    Point _bottomRight;

public:
    Rectangle(const Point &, const Point &);

public:
    const Point &getTopLeft() const;
    const Point &getBottomRight() const;
    float getWidth() const;
    float getHeight() const;
};
```

Rectangle.cpp

```
#include "Rectangle.h"

Rectangle::Rectangle(const Point &topLeft, const Point &bottomRight)
{
    if (topLeft.getX() > bottomRight.getX() || topLeft.getY() > bottomRight.getY()) {
        throw std::invalid_argument("You must specify valid top-left/bottom-right points");
    }
    this->_topLeft = topLeft;
    this->_bottomRight = bottomRight;
}

const Point &Rectangle::getTopLeft() const
{
    return this->_topLeft;
}

const Point &Rectangle::getBottomRight() const
{
    return this->_bottomRight;
}

float Rectangle::getWidth() const
{
    return this->_bottomRight.getX() - this->_topLeft.getX();
}

float Rectangle::getHeight() const
{
    return this->_bottomRight.getY() - this->_topLeft.getY();
}
```

Point.h

```
#pragma once

#include <ostream>
#include <cmath>

class Point {

private:
    float _x;
    float _y;

public:
    Point(float = 0, float = 0);

public:
    float distance(const Point &);

public:
    float getX() const;
    float getY() const;
    void setX(float);
    void setY(float);
};

std::ostream &operator<<(std::ostream &, const Point &);
bool operator==(const Point &, const Point &);
bool operator!=(const Point &, const Point &);
```

Point.cpp

```
#include "Point.h"

Point::Point(float x, float y)
{
    this->_x = x;
    this->_y = y;
}

float Point::distance(const Point &other)
{
    return std::sqrt(std::pow(this->_x - other.getX(), 2) + std::pow(this->_y - other.getY(), 2));
}

float Point::getX() const
{
    return this->_x;
}

float Point::getY() const
{
    return this->_y;
}

void Point::setX(float x)
{
    this->_x = x;
}

void Point::setY(float y)
{
    this->_y = y;
}

std::ostream &operator<<(std::ostream &out, const Point &point)
{
    out << "(" << point.getX() << ", " << point.getY() << ")";
    return out;
}

bool operator==(const Point &p1, const Point &p2)
{
    return p1.getX() == p2.getX() && p1.getY() == p2.getY();
}

bool operator!=(const Point &p1, const Point &p2)
{
    return p1.getX() != p2.getX() || p1.getY() != p2.getY();
}
```

A lot of questions come with this snippet of code.

- This does not compile because obviously whenever we try to create a Polygon, it ends up trying to create a Rectangle with a default constructor which does not exist.
- I can't use initializer list because obviously the bounding box depends on some computed values from my list of points.
- I could create a default constructor creating two Point(0, 0) by default for the Rectangle but this does not make much sense.
- I could use pointers but then I feel this is not the nicest solution as I tend to think this is mostly used for polymorphism in C++ we should prefer reference whenever possible.

How should I then proceed ?

I feel I am missing something out about C++ and could learn a lot from this.

Comment: You should not be using a reference *or* a pointer in this situation, but an actual object. That's what you've declared in your header, so all you need to do is fix the problems as they occur. Make a default constructor for `Rectangle`, or assign it to a default (empty) rectangle in the constructor.

Comment: Show us `Rectangle` class as well.

Comment: I am not an expert, I understand the concept of default argument and how they should be used and to me it does not seems right to create a Rectangle without passing anything, I mean what is really semantically a default rectangle ? 

I added the Rectangle class.

Comment: `Rectangle *Polygon::getBoundingBox() const` is a mismatch, the `*` should be `&`.  Although I would consider returning by value for this (and most of your getters). Returning by reference is an attempt to sacrifice simplicity for performance, but with small objects it's not always clear if this is a performance gain or a performance loss.  You lose copy elision, for one thing.

Comment: @M.M I fixed the small error (mostly because I tried different things over the past few hours and whenever I posted here I forgot this one)

I am currently a student and I am not allowed to pass class by value for pure grading reason that's why everything is always by reference in my code. I am not aware of all the performance reason but the question is mostly between pointer/reference and default constructor or not.and the workaround.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your main question is about how to deal with the problem of needing to initialize both `std::list<Point> _points;` and `Rectangle _boundingBox;`, while also doing some validation of `_points`.

The simplest solution is to just give `Rectangle` a default constructor (or pass two default Points as initializer). Then once you have validated the `points` argument in the constructor, you calculate the `Rectangle` based on the points.

---

A slightly more complicated alternative is to allow the validation function to be invoked from the ctor-initializer list, e.g.:

```
Polygon::Polygon(std::list<Point> points)
    : _points( validate_point_list(points), std::move(points) ), _boundingBox( calculateBoundingBox(_points) ) 
{
}
```

where you have functions (which could be free functions):

```
void validate_point_list(std::list<Point> &points)
{
    if (points.size() < polygon::MIN_SIDE + 1)
        throw std::invalid_argument("A polygon is composed of at least 3 sides.");

    if (points.front() != points.back())
        throw std::invalid_argument("A polygon must be closed therefore the first point must be equal to the last one.");

// caller must pass in same first and last point, but we only store one of the two
    points.erase( points.begin() );
}
```

and

```
Rectangle calculateBoundingBox(std::list<Point> const &_points)
{
    // whatever logic you have in setBoundingBox, except return the answer
}
```

Note that the loop in your Polygon constructor is unnecessarily complicated. You could have just written `_points = points;` and then erased the extra point (which is O(1) for lists).

---

Note that I have passed by value and then used `std::move`. The reason is that if the argument given is a rvalue then it can just be moved right on through into where it's being stored; whereas with the `const &` version, a copy is stored and then the original is destructed.

I would use `const &` a lot less than you did. Small objects , such as `Point` and `Rectangle`, don't suffer a performance penalty from pass-by-value (and might even be more efficient that way). And as mentioned in the previous paragraph; if your function accepts a parameter and it is going to take a copy of that parameter, it's better to pass by value .

Passing by reference is best only when you are using but not storing the values passed. For example, `calculateBoundingBox`.

---

Finally, once you get this working, you might want to think about having the Polygon constructor accept an iterator pair of points range, and/or a `std::initializer_list`.

Answer (score 0):

I feel as though you should have a separate class called BoundingBox that 
1) Takes a collection of points in its constructor
2) Is inherited from Rectangle

Meanwhile, Rectangle should have a state, along the lines of NOT_A_RECTANGLE or it could throw an exception. Just be sure you clean up when throwing exceptions from a constructor.

Then you would construct the bounding box as part of the construction of the polygon and you can verify that a bounding box is possible as part of your error checking. (probably rather than 3 sides check, but I am no geometry expert)

BoundingBox would remain a member of Polygon.

This would be more RTTI.

It occurs to me though, that if you translate or rotate the polygon, you've also go to translate or rotate the bounding box. You might want to consider making the list of points its own object and sharing them. This would be a more advanced topic. You can for now get away with just recalculating the bounding box on operations performed upon the polygon.

As to whether to use a reference, a pointer, or pass by value, I don't know that there is a black and white list of things to consider for this, but a few are:

Is the object large enough to even worry about it? A rectangle is 4 floats?

Are there interfaces or base classes you will need to cast to, rather than always using the class itself? If so, you've got no choice but to use a pointer of some sort. The pointer could be unique, shared, weak, etc. depending on the situation. You have to ask yourself who owns it, whats the life time, and are there circular references?

Most people will probably use a reference whenever possible rather than a pointer, but only when passing by value doesn't qualify.

IMO, since you are just "GetBoundingBox", I think it would be simple and more maintainable to just return a copy of the bounding box by value rather than some const reference and definitely more than a pointer.

Answer (score 0):

I would defined a default constructor for `Rectangle` class as private and I would make `Polygon` class a friend of `Rectangle` class:

```
class Rectangle {
  friend class Polygon;

  Point _topLeft;
  Point _bottomRight;

  Rectangle(); // accessible only to friends

  public:

  Rectangle(Point const&, Point const&);
  ...
};
```

And then in `setBoundingBox()`:

```
void Polygon::setBoundingBox() {
  ...
  _boundingBox._topLeft     = Point(xMin, yMin);
  _boundingBox._bottomRight = Point(xMax, yMax);
}
```

Thus, I wouldn't expose the default constructor of `Rectangle` and at the same time I would have a concrete object which is more efficient in terms of cache performance.

Answer (score 0):

One solution would be to write a programmatic constructor for Rectangle that takes as its argument a `const std::list<Point>&`.  It could traverse the list once, computing the maximum and minimum *x* and *y*.  Then, your `Polygon` constructor would become:

```
Polygon::Polygon(const std::list<Point> &points)
: _points(points),
: _boundingBox(points)
{
  // ...
}
```

An alternative is to move the code to find the bounding box from a list of points to a helper function, then define a move constructor `Rectangle::Rectangle( Rectangle&& x )`.  In that case, your `Polygon` constructor would be:

```
Polygon::Polygon(const std::list<Point> &points)
: _points(points),
: _boundingBox( findBoundingBox(points) )
{
  // ...
}
```

Either way, you could update a bounding box with assignment, so you might want an assignment operator like `Rectangle& Rectangle::operator= ( Rectangle&& x )` to make that more efficient.  You can skip the `Rectangle&&` versions if a `Rectangle` is just Plain Old Data.  But if you do this a lot, you might overload `Rectangle& findBoundingBox( const std::list<Point>& src, Rectangle& dest )` to update in place with no copying.

On a minor side note, I’d discourage you from using identifiers that begin with underscores, since those names are reserved in the global namespace in C++, and your libraries might declare something named `_point`.